# Is it possible to declare a common object of database connection i.e $conn in DBAL symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, dbal

I am working on DBAL symfony2. I have made the database connection using DBAL in  this way
    public function demoAction() {
        $conn = $this->get('database_connection');
     }
i am stuck @ is there any way in which global object / constant that can be declared for connection, instead of calling it on every action.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Global objects is not a best practice in symfony2.
What you can do is create a BaseController, and make all your controllers extend this base controller :

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function getDBAL() 
    {
        return $this->get('database_connection');
    }
}
```

Note that using DBAL in Controller is still a bad practice. You should declare a service for the entities you want to manage.